# Have Hudson call multiple exec:java with profiles

Tags: maven-2, hudson, exec

I have a maven pom in which I've define some profiles.
Each profile defines its own configuration for executing an [exec:java](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) goal. This exec:java invokes a java program that will do some work, which does not relies upon artifact compilation (but what I find very useful to put in maven pom).

What I would like to do is have Hudson compile my java program, then invoke all these profile's exec:java tasks. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [**matrix project**](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Building+a+matrix+project) with a single axis (and as much values as profiles) and use property based profile activation.

Comment: Are matrix Project offered by a Hudson plugin ? I can find no way to create one using my Hudson 1.379.

Comment: @Riduidel I don't have a Hudson under the hand to give detailed steps but IIRC it's not a plugin, it's a job type.

Comment: OK, I found it, it's called in french "multi-configuration project" ... not that explicit.